# Stimulus Controllers Not Functioning At All In Rails 7 App

Tags: javascript, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7, stimulusjs, import-maps

I'm really struggling to get Stimulus controllers to function in a Rails 7 app I'm working on and would appreciate any help anyone might have. I've been spinning my wheels forever.

My Application.js

```
// Configure your import map in config/importmap.rb. Read more: https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails
import "@hotwired/turbo-rails";
import "controllers";
import 'bootstrap';
```

I have Stimulus pinned in the importmap.rb per below:

```
pin "application", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/turbo-rails", to: "turbo.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus-loading", to: "stimulus-loading.js", preload: true
pin "jquery", to: "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.0/dist/jquery.js"
pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"
```

I haven't touched the javascript/controllers/application.js or index.js files.

My Stimulus Controller (ingredients-controller.js):

```
import { Controller } from '@hotwired/stimulus';

export default class extends Controller {

  connect () {
    console.log('HELLOOO!!!!');
  }
  addIngredients(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('test');
  }
}
```

Connected `<div>` in my view below. All I'm trying at the moment is to get the `<button>` element to preventDefault() and do a test alert. I can't get any response from the Stimulus Controller above.

```
<div data-controller="ingredients">
  <turbo-frame id=<%= f.field_id(:ingredents) %>>
    <h2>Add Ingredients</h2>

    <%# Selection section %>
    <div>
      <h6>Spirits</h6>
      <%= f.collection_select :spirit_id, Spirit.all, :id, :spirit_type, {}, { :size => "5", :multiple => true } %>

      <h6>Mixers</h6>

      <%= f.collection_select :mixer_id, Mixer.all, :id, :mixer_type, {}, { :size => "5", :multiple => true } %>

      <h6>Garnishes</h6>

      <%= f.collection_select :garnish_id, Garnish.all, :id, :garnish_type, {}, { :size => "5", :multiple => true } %>
    </div>

    <%# Selected Ingredients %>
  </turbo-frame>

  <button data-action="click->ingredients#addIngredients">Add Ingredients</button>
</div>
```

If anyone has any idea what I'm missing here it would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem (though with JS bundler) and I solved it by installing Stimulus manually. You can find the instructions here: https://github.com/hotwired/stimulus-rails

You may need to first run `rails assets:clobber` to decompile all the assets you have compiled already
and after you finish the manual installation of Stimulus perhaps you should run `yarn build --watch` in another Terminal tab (the same way you would run rails s)

So the steps:

1. run `rails assets:clobber`
2. Add the `stimulus-rails` gem to your Gemfile: `gem 'stimulus-rails'`
3. Run `./bin/bundle install`
4. Follow the instructions for the manual installation (under the subheader "With import map") from https://github.com/hotwired/stimulus-rails.
5. Run `yarn build --watch` in an additional tab
6. Test your Stimulus controller

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks Gogamar! This worked. I followed these steps and I also rearranged my import statements in application.js so that import 'jquery' was at the top. It was at the bottom previously and cut off in my post above. Not sure if that was causing a problem as well, but everything working now.

Comment: Thank you!  I have been battling trying to get my stimulus controllers to work with compiled assets and this finally seems to have got it going.  For me, it was simply following the steps on the stimulus-rails page you referenced in step 4. Somehow my environment must have been out of date.

Answer (score 4):

For anyone who configured their rails 7 app to work with bootstrap (using the top links on google), it messes with the javascript mapping and breaks stimulus. Not sure about a solution yet.

Comment: The newest version does not work properly with Bootstrap5 and Rails7, I used older versions and they worked for me - https://cdnjs.com/libraries/slim-select/2.3.3

Comment: They must have fixed it already because my newly created rails project with bootstrap option works fine with stimulus

Comment: I have edited my answer above. Adding config.assets.digest = false in config/environments/development.rb fixed that on my side.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, I had to manually edit my `app/javascript/controllers/index.js` to register the controller.

For exemple, after a `rails g component dropdown`, I needed to edit the `index.js` as follow (the command in the comment `./bin/rails stimulus:manifest:update` didn't update correctly the file...)

```
// app/javascript/controllers/index.js
// This file is auto-generated by ./bin/rails stimulus:manifest:update
// Run that command whenever you add a new controller or create them with
// ./bin/rails generate stimulus controllerName

import { application } from "./application"

import DropdownController from "../../components/dropdown_component/dropdown_component_controller"
application.register("dropdown", DropdownController)
```

**EDIT: For Rails 7 & Bootstrap 5**

At some point, changes in stimulus controllers were not working: nothing happened... And new controllers were not registered anymore.

Adding `config.assets.digest = false` in `config/environments/development.rb` fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

Switching to lazy load somehow helped me.

```
// app/javascript/controllers/index.js

import { application } from "controllers/application"

import { lazyLoadControllersFrom } from "@hotwired/stimulus-loading"
lazyLoadControllersFrom("controllers", application)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem too when following dhh's chat app video, but none of those `rails assets:clobber`  worked for me. I was using esbuild not importmaps.

The issue was with controller naming of `./bin/rails stimulus:manifest:update` method. Instead of naming multiple worded controllers with sub dash `_`  it turns out it names them with regular dash `-` which took my hours to find out. so check it out.

sample: `reset_form` vs `reset-form` naming in **app/javascript/controllers/index.js** file

```
import ResetFormController from "./reset_form_controller"
application.register("reset-form", ResetFormController)
```

on your views it should be:

`data: { controller: "reset-form", action: "turbo:submit-end->reset-form#reset" }) do |form| %>`

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with stimulus upgrade from an older version where the first line of each controller is like this

```js
import { Controller } from 'stimulus';
```

it has to be changed to

```js
import { Controller } from '@hotwired/stimulus';
```

problem is that the stimulus library was properly starting but never complained about controllers with older import

Answer (score 0):

I started a new Rails 7.1.3.2 app from scratch and this is what worked for me:

1. Add `gem 'sprockets-rails'` to the Gemfile manually and run `bin/install`
2. Run `rails s` and follow all the errors. I was first prompted to create a `app/assets/config/manifest.js` file and to restart my server; each time I restarted, it would prompt me with which file was missing from the `manifest.js`. For a clean install, this should be:

```
//= link application.css
//= link application.js
//= link controllers/application.js
//= link controllers/hello_controller.js
//= link controllers/index.js
```

but you can start with a blank `manifest.js` file, restart the server, and follow the instructions one by one.

3. Go to `hello_controller.js` and replace everything inside the `connect` function with a `console.log` message.
4. Go to the `.erb` file you want to connect the controller to and add `data-controller="hello"` to an existing div.
5. Restart the server.

The `console.log` message showed up, showing the connection was correct.

I did not have to change any settings in `config/environments` as suggested in many other solutions, and both `rails generate stimulus <name>` and `rails stimulus:manifest:update` worked as intended. The only thing I had to do manually was add any new controllers to `manifest.js`, which you will be prompted to do with an error message anyway.