# Rails 7 App (Webpack) Javascript is not loading

Tags: javascript, ruby, webpack, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-7

I created a rails 7 app with the following template:
rails new 
-d postgresql 
-j webpack 
-m https://raw.githubusercontent.com/lewagon/rails-templates/master/devise.rb 
CHANGE_THIS_TO_YOUR_RAILS_APP_NAME

everything is working fine, but once I wanted to add a boostrap Modal I noticed that my javascript isn't loading into the application.html.erb. I can't even simply console.log("hello"), which confuses me. This is what my application.html.erb looks like:

[Application.html.erb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qp1PU.png)

This is what my File structure looks like including application.js
[File structure and application.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pVXZJ.png)

I tried channging the java script tags in application.html.erb, tried reinstalling webpack, tried a different template, but can't seem to get it to work. I would be greatful for any tips

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this answer can help you : [Stimulus Controllers Not Functioning At All In Rails 7 App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73902158/stimulus-controllers-not-functioning-at-all-in-rails-7-app/73922614#73922614)

> You may need to first run rails assets:clobber to decompile all the
> assets you have compiled already and after you finish the manual
> installation of Stimulus perhaps you should run yarn build --watch in
> another Terminal tab (the same way you would run rails s)
>
> So the steps:
>
> run rails assets:clobber
>
> Add the stimulus-rails gem to your Gemfile: gem 'stimulus-rails'
>
> Run ./bin/bundle install
>
> Follow the instructions for the manual installation (under the
> subheader "With import map") from
> https://github.com/hotwired/stimulus-rails.
>
> Run yarn build --watch in an additional tab
>
> Test your Stimulus controller
>
> Hope it helps!